# How can I get the div information via js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have div named  $(".aDiv"), how can I get the $(".aDiv") position, and the information about $(".Div") using js? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what information you're after.  For the position for example, there's [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (relative to the offset parent) and [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (relative to the document), like this:

```
var topCornerFromDocument = $(".aDiv").offset().top;
//or...
var leftCornerFromDocument = $(".aDiv").offset().left;
```

For other information there are [many functions](http://api.jquery.com/) it depends what you're after - [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for attributes, [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for style properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/position/

http://api.jquery.com/offset/